# Why @import google font javascript readyState not complete

Tags: javascript, css

I import font from google but chrome and Firefox state show log states "interactive" not complete

css

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;600;700;900&display=swap');
```

javascript

```
switch (document.readyState) {
    case "loading":
        // The document is still loading.
        console.log("load");
        break;
    case "interactive":
        console.log("interactive");
        break;
    case "complete":
        console.log("completed");
        break;
}
```

Comment: From what I can *tell*, it's because of the load order of the DOM; the stylesheet has to be ready before the document is ready. But ultimately, the document has already loaded the stylesheet, so does it really matter exactly *when* the stylesheet was loaded in the process? Styles will always apply when used correctly; timing is never an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, You havent linked your css file to your javascript file, OR you havent shown it here, you can link it by this line of code:

```js
import './mystyle.css'
```

Secondly, in your css file, you havent targeted anything after importing your font, to target everything, you can simply use `*` like this:

```css
* {
 font: 'fontname';
}
```

So, your complete code should look like this:

javascript:

```js
import './mystyle.css';

switch (document.readyState) {
    case "loading":
        // The document is still loading.
        console.log("load");
        break;
    case "interactive":
        console.log("interactive");
        break;
    case "complete":
        console.log("completed");
        break;
}
```

css:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css 2family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;600;700;900&display=swap');

* {
 font:'fontname';
}
```

Comment: You cannot import a stylesheet to a JavaScript file like you would with an ES6 module, unless you explicitly use SystemJS.

Comment: ohhh okay, so do you import it by href?